# Need to alert for unchecked radio buttons in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Example

```
  <div id="radio">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2"  /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="3" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
```

```
 <div id="radio">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="3" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
```

```
  <div id="radio">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" value="3" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
```

The above radio groups are generated dynamically. 
In which I need to identify the radio group which is not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, radio buttons are used for when you want the user to only pick one at a time. So, I think you would rather use checkboxes, rather than radio buttons.

Having said that, I think the easiest way to achieve your goal with jQuery is to use the [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector. This code will get you all checkboxes that are not selected:

```
var notChecked = $('input:not(:checked)')
```

Here's a fiddle with demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nasuf96b/

Obviously there's some error handling that would have to be done, but you get the idea.

Good luck.

### Edit

I see now what you're after. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nasuf96b/1/.
It tells you if nothing in a group has been selected, which I take it is what you want to do.

```
$('input').on('click', function() {
    check_all();   
});

function check_all() {
    var outputText = 'These are not checked: ';
    var myDivs = $('div.radio');
    for (var i=0; i<myDivs.length; i++) {
        var isChecked = false;
        var childInputs = myDivs[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var j=0; j<childInputs.length; j++) {
            if (childInputs[j].checked == true) {
                isChecked = true;
            }
        }
        if (isChecked == false) {
            outputText += (i+1) +', ';   
        }
    }
    alert(outputText.slice(0, -2));
}
```

Comment: I already know this option. This will provide only first radio group . I want all radio group which is not checked.

Comment: That was great..very helpful..thank you..paul..even some person downed me..bt u helped me lot..

Comment: Glad this helped. In that case, can you accept my answer?